# using wp_rewrite but keep the original url in the address bar

Tags: redirect, urls, wp-redirect

My problem is fairly simple : I use the following lines in my theme's functions.php :

```
add_action('init', 'digi_add_rewrite');

function digi_add_rewrite() {
  global $wp_rewrite;
  $wp_rewrite->add_rule('([^/]+)/([^/]+)/menu','index.php?p=1119&d_rest=$matches[1]&d_lang=$matches[2]','top');
  $wp_rewrite->add_rule('([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)','index.php?p=1395&d_rest=$matches[1]&d_lang=$matches[2]&d_dish=$matches[3]','top');

  $wp_rewrite->flush_rules();
}
```

This simply allows me receive an url with something like `.../en` and interpret it as something like `...?d_lang=en`

But my problem is the following : on the client's browser, the URL also gets rewritten from the clean `.../en` to the ugly `...?d_lang=en`.

How to prevent this and keep showing him what he typed unaltered ?

Many thanks !

Comment: Are `d_rest` and `d_lang` query vars that you've added? Is it your own code that is receiving and interpreting this value?

Comment: Yes, I added them and my own code uses them.